# Использование тире

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли ставить тире в данном случае: "Пусть все твои желания будут исполнены, а цели — достигнуты". Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Здесь тире вполне корректно, но и без него не будет ошибкой.
Оно ставится обычно только в нераспространенных предложениях, когда без указания на опущенное слово смысл не столь очевиден.

*Оба предыдущих отвечающих перегнули палку, но Серж все-таки несколько ближе к истине.*

Comment: Может, "не столь очевиден" всё-таки?)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой да, спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Тире ставится на месте пропуска глагола "быть".

Comment: Значит у меня всё верно. Спасибо!